# Widgets movement in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

I want to implement this kind of behaviour:

1) ImageView with logo is shown in the center for a second, while some background loading is going on.
2) ImageView slides up and fragment fades in below it, taking display space from bottom to ImageView's new position.

I've managed to implement the behaviour using ImageView click listener with:

```
 final ConstraintSet newCS = new ConstraintSet();
 newCS.clone(this, R.layout.activity_login);
 newCS.clear(R.id.logo, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

 findViewById(R.id.logo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(la);
         newCS.applyTo(la);
     }
}
```

Clearing bottom constraint I make logo to raise up. Frame for fragment constrained to logo bottom so it stretchs.

But can't make transition begin after activity load. Logo remains in the center until FragmentManager loads fragment. After it, logo jumps straight up without transaction.

Should I even use transitions or go for ObjectAnimator?

I'm lost.

Comment: Maybe make a guideline and animate it's property? Will other widgets update it's positions properly?

Comment: What’s your min API?